# multiple @OneToMany slows down the performance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications, jpa-2.1

Consider the entities below (Getters and Setters removed to reduce code) -

```
public class Organization {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn
  private List<Account> accounts;
}


public class Account {
    
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
    
      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn
      private List<Contact> contacts;
    }


public class Contact {
    
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
    
      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn
      private List<Certification> certifications;
    }


public class Certification {
    
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
    
      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn
      private List<Skill> skills;
    }


public class Skill {
    
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
    
      private String name;
    }
```

I am using spring boot JPA specifications to pull all the organizations having certification in skill say - Java

```
    public static Specification<Organization> getPartner() {
        return (root, cq, cb) -> {
          
              Join<Organization, Skill> skillJoin = root.join("accounts").join("contacts")
                  .join("certifications").join("skills");
              return cb.equal(skillJoin.get("name"), "java");
        }
    }
```

The above code takes 8-9s to return the results. Possibly due to multiple @OneToMany joins.
Any suggestions for performance improvements please :)

Comment: Your code is properly normalized though its good but practically it slows down the performance so we have to denormalize entity up to some extent to make application performance good. I would suggest to add org_id and account_id column in all other tables to remove chained dependency and so in your code too.

Comment: How much data gets returned? What are the SQL statements that actually get executed?  Do you actually need all this data? What execution plan do the statements use? Are those reasonable? Joins are normally only a problem when they cause to much data to be returned, otherwise they are actually pretty efficient.

Comment: I am using spring boot specifications and it takes care of creating the statements internally. I won't need all the data. Mostly Organization and skills data. The example above contains 1 or 2 columns. But in reality I have around 8-10 columns for Org and Skill entity.